# How to display data on ListView when i hover on an item from another Listview?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, listview

So i have this code but doesn't work. Data are taken from MySQL database. Anyone please help. :)

```
ListView1.Items.Clear()
Dim list As New ListViewItem
command.CommandText = "SELECT Quantity, Unit, Product FROM tblPurchase_Products WHERE PO_Number = '" & CInt(***WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE?!***) & "' "
adapter.SelectCommand = command
reader = command.ExecuteReader()
While reader.Read
    list = ListView1.Items.Add(reader.GetString(0))
    list.SubItems.Add(reader.GetString(1))
    list.SubItems.Add(reader.GetString(2))
End While
reader.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use  ListView1_ItemMouseHover Event to display data in another lsitview

```
 Private Sub ListView1_ItemMouseHover(sender As [Object], e As ListViewItemMouseHoverEventArgs)

               your code here

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

CInt = convert to type integer

ex: textbox1.text = 12

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT Quantity, Unit, Product FROM tblPurchase_Products WHERE PO_Number = '" & CInt(textbox1.text) & "' "
```

The conclusion: must be PO_Number

If you can not handle, back it with more information

Comment: This is the 21st Century, Integers have a range of -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06bkb8w2.aspx

Comment: Yes when I said 38 thousand was thinking of something else. Thanks